# Loopback always return true for Bit field in mysql

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using Boolean value in loopback model for mysql field Bit.
It always give true in response even though value of field is 0 in DB.

Comment: can you please post your model and response code ? thank you

Comment: edited question, added my own model, since I have the same issue